# Reset and restart table col with jquery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using jQuery tablesorter plugin to sort my table. As you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fa9s4ztb/1/), there is the possibility to trigger a sort reset with a button.

```
$(function() {
  $("table").tablesorter({
    sortInitialOrder: 'asc'
  });
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('table').trigger('sortReset');
    return false;
  });
});
```

What I want is that clicking on an unsorted column will always sort it in the initial order specified by the sortInitialOrder attribute. For example, click reset, click on a table header, click reset and then again on the same table header. Each time when initiating a new sort the order direction should stay the same which does not happen in the fiddle. The tablesorter has a setting for this use case called "sortRestart", but unfortunately (I don't know why) you cannot trigger it manually. Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The "locked order" option can be use to accomplish this, which is documented [here](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers-locked.html.). It is applied separately to each column header that should be locked.

It can be applied as part of the HTML in a couple of ways (I've left out the metadata method that requires another file):

- Using a data attribute: `<th data-lockedorder="asc">Last Name</th>`

  or
- Using a class: `<th class="lockedOrder-asc">Last Name</th>`

Or the sort order can be locked within the tablesorter code:

```js
headers : { 
    0 : { lockedOrder: 'asc' } 
}
```

These three methods are demonstrated on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2q100/50r94gad/), which is yours with some adjustments.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not was I was asking for. I don't want the order to be locked. When I click on a table header the table should be sorted as one would expect, first click ascending, second click descending and so on. But everytime when I click on the reset button and afterwards on a table header the table should be sorted ascending which doesn't work at the moment.

Comment: What about using the `sortReset : true` option. Clicking a third time on the column heading brings it back to on unsorted state rather than using a reset button. Demonstrated [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f2q100/ppkhedo2/7/)